# Calling AWS AppSync GraphQL API mutation query from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql

I am using AWS web console. I am trying to create lambda function to run my AppSync GraphQL API mutation query. I have seen many answers on web but they all are trying to create lambda on local machine first and then pushing it to AWS cloud. I can't follow this method. I am working directly on AWS web console.

Basically I have a dynamodb database table behind the appsync graphql API. I want to update an entry in dynamoDB using lambda function. To update this entry (in DynamoDB) I need to run a mutation query on appsync graphql API. I want to achieve this using lambda function. I want to call mutation query (of appsync) from lambda.

See the lambda's `node.js` code below:

```
const appsync = require('aws-appsync');
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
require('cross-fetch/polyfill');

const graphqlClient = new appsync.AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: 'APPSYNC_ENDPOINT_URL',
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  auth: {
    type: 'AWS_IAM',
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    }
  },
  disableOffline: true
});

const mutation = gql`mutation Test($value: String!) {
  test(value: $value)
}`;
await graphqlClient.mutate({
  mutation,
  variables: {
    value: 'test'
  }
});
```

I am getting error :

`"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'aws-appsync'"`

The lambda function is trying to use `aws-appsync` but is unable to find it. How do I 'install' this package on the AWS lambda web console? **I am not using my local development machine. I am writing lambda function directly on web console.**

How do I enable `aws-appsync` package in lambda using only the web console ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You could develop the lambda in local environment, add package.json with the dependencies zip the function and node_modules and then upload.

[Deploy Node.js Lambda functions with .zip file archives](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html)